# Function that creates function

Tags: r

I want to create a function that creates a function, which I tried to :

```
function_1<- function(a,b){
  function_2 <- function(x){
    ;x[1]^a*x[2]^b
  }
  
  return(function_2)
}
```

However, when I execute this function and execute fu after saving the

```
fu <- function_1(1,1)
```

I received when executing fu

```
function(x){
    ;x[1]^a*x[2]^b
  }
<environment: 0x000001cc81774c38>
```

But, I want my new function such as:

```
function(x){
    ;x[1]^1*x[2]^1
  }
<environment: 0x000001cc81774c38>
```

So that I can apply it into solnl for constrained optimization. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I didn't receive the expected result with this  one.

Comment: oops should have been `fu <- \(x) function_2(x, 1, 1)`

Comment: So are you claiming this function `fu` doesn't work when you run constrained optimization? Can you please show how you are trying to do that and what errors you are getting? You are creating a closure so the function should work just the same even if it looks a little different.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* your question is about how to pass parameters from an outer function which returns a function to that inner function, so they are already defined when the inner function is evaluated. You can do something like this.

```r
function_1<- function(a,b){
  function_2 <- function(x, aa = a, bb = b){
    x[1]^aa*x[2]^bb
  }
  
  return(function_2)
}
```

If you then run, `fu <- function_1(1,1)`, this gives you:

```r
fu
# function(x, aa = a, bb = b){
#     x[1]^aa*x[2]^bb
#   }
# <bytecode: 0x5c5d8e8>
# <environment: 0x6569fb8>
```

The function has access to `a` and `b` because they were created in the environment in which the function was defined. For more on this, see the [Functional programming](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html) chapter of Advanced R, and particularly the section on [Closures](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#closures).

You can do a common-sense check of this with random parameters e.g.

```r
fu(c(3,4)) == 3^1 * 4^1 # TRUE
all(
    apply(expand.grid(1:10, 1:10), 1, \(x) fu(c(x[1], x[2])) == x[1]^1 * x[2]*1)
) # TRUE
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a **string** of desired function and use **eval** and **parse**:

```
function_1<- function(a,b){
  f2 <- paste("function(x){return(x[1]^",a,"*x[2]^",b,")}",sep="")
  return(eval(parse(text=f2)))
}
fu <- function_1(2,3)
fu
function(x){return(x[1]^2*x[2]^3)}
<environment: 0x55b45d5dd5f0>

xx <- c(2,5)
```

using **fu** functio

```
fu(xx)
```

will produce

```
500
```